# Yii v1.1 redirects to 404 nginx

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, server, yii, pretty-urls

My Yii 1.1 app redirects to `site.com/login` and gets error 404. Yii app hasn't any problems, it's an old app which I want to install on my server. The problem has to be with nginx configuration with `mod_rewrite` because pretty urls are not processed as they should.

Here i my default.conf:

```
server {
 include snippets/phpmyadmin.conf;
 listen   80 default_server;
    charset UTF-8;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /home/fornex/tmp_7offers/public/;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        server_name localhost;

          client_max_body_size  30m;

  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 60;

        location /public {
                root /home/fornex/tmp_7offers/public/;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                error_log  /var/log/nginx/error-01.log;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;
                # proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                # proxy_http_version 1.1;
                # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                # proxy_set_header Host $host;
                # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;


                if (!-e $request_filename){
                   rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?r=$1 last;
                 }

        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    include fastcgi_params;
    # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;


    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;



        if ($request_uri ~ ^/(login)) {
            error_page      404     =301 @redirect;
        }
    # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
     #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

How can I enable `mod_rewrite` so pretty urls will processed as they should?